# SQL Injection on INSERT

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-injection

I'm currently testing Vulnerabiltys to SQL Injections for my companys application as an it-trainee.

So I found, that the application is indeed vulnerable to injections because I can alter some of the insert statements.

So I altered the `insert` Statement to this:

```
INSERT INTO tablename( column, column1, column2, column3, column4,column5, column6, column7, column8 ) 
VALUES ( 10965972, 185796154, 25, 23,2023, '', CURRENT_DATE, 'v0201100',
18); 

DELETE * 
  FROM tablename;-- , 2023,'a', CURRENT_DATE, 'v0201100', 18 )
```

I thought this should be a correct statement, but the MySQL Server returned this Error:
MySQL Error: 1064 (You have an error in your SQL syntax;[...]

Would be nice if somebody could help and tell my why the syntax is wrong...

Thanks for your help :-)

Edit:
Thanks for all your answers. :) Unfortunatly the * wasn't the Problem.
I tried to execute the statement (statement is executed by php) without the delete part
so the statement looks like this:

[...] VALUES( 10963455, 182951959, 23, 23,2023, '', CURRENT_DATE, 'v0201100', 18)--, 2023, '', CURRENT_DATE, 'v0201100', 18 )

But even then the MySQL Server returned the Same Error.
Here is the Full Error Message:

> MySQL Error: 1064 (You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near '--, 2023, '', CURREN' at line
>   17) Session halted.

Would really appreciate it if anyone knew the problem.

Comment: Hi freddy, welcome to SO. Tell us what "engine" executes the query (i.e. PHP). Also, in MySQL's error message, `[...]` actually tells you where the error is. Can you provide that too?

Comment: The comment itself should be valid, but perhaps it needs a space between the statement and the comment.

Answer (score 5):

Having a look at the [MySQL spec for DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html), there is no suggestion that you can include `*` immediately proceeding the DELETE statement. Try removing it.

The `*` is used in a select statement to select all columns. Specifying it here makes no sense, as you are deleting rows.

I believe the `--` commented-out line will be ignored by the parser (I would certainly expect it to be), so that bit of code should be ok. If in doubt remove it as a test.

Comment: It seems the -- really is the problem. It tried to use # and /* but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 5):

If that sample chunk of query is executed in a *SINGLE* `->query()` call, MySQL's driver doesn't allow multiple queries within a single query call. It eliminates the [bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com) type injection attacks, but doesn't prevent injecting values that would manipulate where clauses and whatnot.

Comment: +1. Like this answer. Didn't realise you could do this. I wonder if there is an alternative in .NET land...

Answer (score 0):

When I split your sql statement on multiple lines using ; as seperator, I get:

1) VALUES( 10965972, 185796154, 25, 23,2023, '', CURRENT_DATE, 'v0201100', 18);
2) DELETE * FROM tablename; 
3) -- , 2023, 'a', CURRENT_DATE, 'v0201100', 18 )

To me, 3) doesn't look like valid sql to me...

Comment: It's a comment, so it's valid SQL.

Comment: I believe that is a valid MySQL comment and will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't allow a `delete` query without a `where` statement. You can use:

```
DELETE * FROM tablename WHERE 1 = 1
```

You may also have to remove the `*` after `delete`, it doesn't look like MySQL supports that.

Comment: Are you sure? In the Docs linked to from James's answer it says `[WHERE where_condition]` I thought square brackets meant not required.

Comment: Is that so? The spec for DELETE (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) implies that it is optional.

Comment: I thought `DELETE FROM tablename` would be enough for deleting everything. You cannot delete just one column...

Comment: @Martin, James: It seems that this restriction has been dropped somewhere along the way. Earlier versions definitely had it.

Comment: @Guffa: And I suppose there's nothing to say @freddy isn't using one of these earlier versions. Worth a try.

Comment: The restriction applies to MySQL's safe-mode. If enabled you weren't allowed to do updates or deletes without a where clause. To prevent accidentally destroying your entire table. I don't know if the option is still available but statements without a where clause are valid.

Answer (score 0):

@freddy: `DELETE * FROM tablename` should be `DELETE FROM tablename`.

Answer (score 0):

ANSI SQL definition for DELETE statements does not include an asterix *

Try, `DELETE FROM tablename`

Answer (score -1):

Additionally you are using a SQL-Injection. The reason why SQL-Injections are possible at your company is a secret (just use preapred statements), but this isn't the question. Most SQL-Injections are caused by using mysql_query() without filtering/escaping. mysql_query() allows only 1 query. There has to be mysql_multi_query() if this should work.
Modifying data in SELECT-Statements is prohibited by MySQL.